# How to compare form data with table data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple challenge. Am creating a system and one of the things it does is to take user input form data and searches the data from the database table and returns the most accurate value that according to the various inputs.

Comment: Could you give us some code for better understanding?

Comment: I don't have a sample code, I just need an assistance on how I can go about it. But this is how it flows. The users puts the amount he has, selects the location and the searches for the possible business he that is more nearly matches the query from the table and then displays it.

Comment: "what does the table look like?" "what does the form look like?" "how is the 'most accurate value' determined?" are all questions I have about your system... (I would recommend you start by answering the two questions "what does the table look like?" and "how is the 'most accurate value' determined?"... at that point what the form should look like should become relatively clear... and having reached that point.. you would be left with questions that have clear and definite answers that we could help you to find... but as it stands... your question is so vague, it is a statement)

Comment: the table has name of the location, the amount, name of the business. so when one submits the form data, the system is supposed to look at the various amounts close to the user input, searches for the location close to the user input. and then puts that which is close to the user inputs

Comment: make sure you update your question with additional information (as opposed to just responding to the comments)... it's much easier to glean all of the useful information, if it is neatly set out in the question rather than scattered across the comments

Answer (score 0):

You should use a scope to check the table for data that is similar to the input you receive from your form.

```
scope :find_business, lambda { |user_input| where("business LIKE ?", "%#{user_input}%") }
```

The scope will go in your model and you can call it in your controller after receiving form input from the user. Hope this helps some.

% is a wildcard in SQL meaning 0 or more characters. This means if the user_input is "Pizza", this scope will find "Rob's Pizza", "Pizza Palace" and any business with "Pizza" in your database.